# capture traffic of an android app

Tags: debugging, android, patch-reversing, wireshark, proxy

I was trying to test and intercept traffic from an app developed on **Rhodes** open source framework, I setup a proxy with burp, and of course I have installed burp certificate on my device hence I can intercept other apps on my device but I am unable to see the traffic of the app in [question - its link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) on burp suite instead the app works fine and connects to the remote server without even appearing any error related to certificate on the **event Log** of the burp suite. in reversing the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) I concluded that it is using https protocol to connect to the server(would be happy to confirm it [app link here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US)). in my testing when I have installed the app in a Genymotion Emulator and burp suite set up to intercept traffic, can only see **traffic** going to local host address; forexample:

```
http://127.0.0.1:44895

POST /app/Settings/do_pathlogin HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:44895
Content-Length: 65
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:44895
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Samsung Galaxy S6 Build/OPR6.170623.017; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
Transition-Enabled: true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:44895/app/Settings/index_callback
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
Connection: close

fromPage=login&operation_key=HOME_REP&username=user&password=pass
```

I don't have any idea why this behaviour the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) is showing, in the real device this won't show up, i.e, traffic to the address `127.0.0.1`.
As other researchers would recommend, tried to sniff network traffic of the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) with wireshark  and activated the capture traffic of the wireshark, I was expecting to sniff or even decide whether app is using UDP protocols, but did not appear any traffic from the app!.

**I wanted some help how can I capture the traffic of this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US)?**

**what am I missing?**

**what other steps do I need?**

I would really happy to help me about this.

You can get the app in question [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US)

Comment: The application check your certiciate and rejects the BURP one, you need to bypass certificate pinning inside your application to sniff the traffic.

Comment: did you confirm it plz? I didn't see any error logs complaining about burp certificate! may be I am missing something

Comment: Have you installed Burp root certificate as system certificate (not user certificate!) on the test device?

Comment: Nope, I only installed it in the user certificate section. Would be happy if you give me steps to install burp certificate in the system credentials for **genymotion** emulator. Nevertheless if it was certificate issue, why I cannot see an error log in burp? The app does connect to the server without an issue in real device when burp was still on.

Comment: Mitmproxy documentation contains an [how-to install the rot CA cert as system cert](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/). But you should first install your root Ca cert as user certificate so you get the correct file as `c8450d0d.0` is only the valid name for the mitmproxy root ca cert. However I would recommend to use a real phone. Banking apps often refuse to work on emulators.

Comment: @Robert I did it! but still showing same behavior. the traffic is still going to ```127.0.0.1```

Comment: As I said I strongly recommend to do the tests on a real test device. Emulators are easily to detect and banking apps "don't like to be reversed".